# Getting segmentation fault after ubuntu upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualenv

Our remote server has been recently upgraded, I used to use anaconda3 for the envs, now whatever command I type that has path anaconda bin folder gives a segmentation fault.

```
$ conda list
Segmentation fault
$ which conda
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

**Update**
I ran the gdb debugger (`gdb python`), and this is the following error I have got.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff782ebbf in __libc_start_main () from /home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff782ebbf in __libc_start_main () from /home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x000055555572f062 in _start () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:103
```

Comment: 16.04 is also EOL as of April 2021.

Comment: How exactly did you install Anaconda? What version of Anaconda do you have? The Ubuntu upgrade probably replaced some libraries. Maybe the old Anaconda is no longer compatible with the newer libraries. You could try to reinstall Anaconda or maybe try a newer version...

Comment: I had Anaconda3, I had installed new Anaconda3 altogether I tried to rsyn envs but that too din workout.